# How to run function after images finished resizing in browser? (JS/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-resizing

I have a page with two packs of images (large and small ones, like 10-30 of them), their size must be adjusted on the fly to the current browser window size, and then processed by another function. 
I know that resizing in browser is generally bad idea, but so are the requirements + legacy code on server. Site uses JQuery.

Code (shortened one) looks like the following:

```
imageResizeBox(imgSmallHeight, '.box img'); // resize images to some height, parameters are size and selector
imageResizeBox(imgBigHeight, '.imagebig img'); // resize other images to another     height
processImages(); // process both packs of images (do positioning based on new dimensions)
```

This is the resize function:

```
function imageResizeBox(size, selector) {
var max_size = size;


$(selector).each(function (i) {
    if (this.complete) {
        resizeImg(this);
    } else {
        $(this).load(function () {
            resizeImg(this);
        });
    }
});

function resizeImg(img) {
    if ($(img).height() > $(img).width()) {
        var h = max_size;
        var w = Math.ceil($(img).width() / $(img).height() * max_size);
    } else {
        var w = max_size;
        var h = Math.ceil($(img).height() / $(img).width() * max_size);
    }
    $(img).css({
        height:h,
        width:w
    });
}
```

}

I need to call processImages() function after first two functions are completed in browser (image resizing is complete in full), otherwise positioning is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, I've solved the problem. Actually I needed image sizes to be correct before positioning script applied. So, I added image width and height attributes to the <img> tag on server, and on DOM load manipulated using those numbers, no matter if images were loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

call your code inside a

```
$(document).ready(**call your code here**);
```

ready runs after all images load, see spec http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: $(document).ready checks if DOM is ready, it doesn't check if images are loaded by browser, that's the issue.

Comment: welp i was reading on jquery site: "While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received." still images can be loaded and not drawn, is that the case?

Comment: I was getting image sizes from files itself, it was bad approach. Solved by adding width/height attributes to the img tag on server, so they are available on DOM load by $(document).ready(). Thanks anyway )